# Virtualenv PyDev Undefined variable from import error

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, numpy, pydev, virtualenv

First of all I'm aware of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors) but I couldn't find a satisfied answer there. I don't want to ignore errors or use comments - I want to have the right settings in eclipse/pydev. My problem is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842194/undefined-variable-from-import-when-importing-numpy-in-eclipse-pydev).

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed a virtuenv for python 2.7 in my home directory. After installing several python packages (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc.) using pip, I installed eclipse 4.3 with pydev.

If I use the python system interpreter at `/usr/bin/python` everything works fine (except that I didn't want to use). However, if I try to set up a python interpreter using the virtualenv first I get this warning describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595276/pydev-eclipse-python-interpreters-error-stdlib-not-found). After clicking "proceed anyway", it seems to work. So far so good.

However e.g. `import numpy as np` gives for each `np.*` call the eclipse/pydev error `Undefined variable from import`, also the code completion doesn't work properly. It seems to work, e.g. for datetime, but not for numpy, scipy and matplotlib.

Does anybody figured out to configure eclipse correctly?

I already tried to add the numpy path manually to the virtualenv interpreter, but than I get the weird error:

`import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
  File "/home/pydev/myenv-py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/init.py", line 149, in 
    import sys, os, tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in 
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name Random`