# Undefined variable from import when using vtk

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, code-analysis, vtk

I am coding in python 2.7 using python-vtk 6.2.0 installed with the Ubuntu package manager.
I use eclipse + pydev as IDE and I can run the code successfully in shell and from within eclipse.

The only annoying problem I have is that the code analyser keeps posting errors of the type: `Undefined variable from import: vtkxxxxxx` whenever I do

```
import vtk

vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter
vtk.vtkActor
vtk.vtkWhatever
```

I tried to reset the interpreter and I have also tried to manually add the library .so files to the PYTHONPATH, with no luck.

Also I can see the the vtk package in the project tree under system libs and I have no errors on the line `import vtk`

Is there a particular unusual way to include vtk library in pydev? Am I doing something stupid I do not see?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

I have found a similar question already asked about numpy. It has been solved so maybe you might find your answer in there. The URL for the issue is https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082269/7171962

Btw. This may be of no help to you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No this doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks by the way!

Comment: No problem. Anytime.

Answer (score 1):

had you gone through this link [enter link description here](http://kazenotaiyo.blogspot.in/2010/06/installing-vtk-in-ubuntu-and-making.html)

Hope this will help

Comment: Yes I did it, unfortunately it  does not seem to solve the issue.